# Preprocessor check if multiple defines are not defined

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a selection of #defines in a header that are user editable and so I subsequently wish to check that the defines exist in case a user deletes them altogether, e.g.

```
#if defined MANUF && defined SERIAL && defined MODEL
    // All defined OK so do nothing
#else
    #error "User is stoopid!"
#endif
```

This works perfectly OK, I am wondering however if there is a better way to check if multiple defines are NOT in place... i.e. something like:

```
#ifn defined MANUF || defined SERIAL ||.... // note the n in #ifn
```

or maybe

```
#if !defined MANUF || !defined SERIAL ||....
```

to remove the need for the empty #if section.

Comment: FYI: `defined` is an operator that is invoked like a function (just like `sizeof`. So if you call it like a function, your example will work fine. Also - you can use most logical operators (`==`, `!=`, `!`, `||`, `&&`) in preprocessor statements as well.

Comment: It's a general principle of boolean algebra that you can replace `!(x && y)` with `(!x || !y)`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
#if !defined(MANUF) || !defined(SERIAL) || !defined(MODEL)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add the parens or can it be
"#if !defined MANUF || ..."?

Comment: @TimK From what is written above, I'd say "yes". I could well be wrong; this is just an assumption.

Comment: Actually you don't, but I'd recommend it for readability. https://godbolt.org/g/O48eun

Comment: Really? This seems easier to read to me, but it might just be personal preference: `#if !defined MANUF || !defined SERIAL || !defined MODEL`

Comment: One benefit to the parens is that if `MANUF` happens to be a compound statement (ie. 1 + 1) then you'll be checking the whole statement, not just the first piece of it.

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, @SergeyL's answer is great, but here is a slight variant for testing.  Note the change in logical or to logical and.

main.c has a main wrapper like this:

```
#if !defined(TEST_SPI) && !defined(TEST_SERIAL) && !defined(TEST_USB)
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // the true main() routine.
}
```

spi.c, serial.c and usb.c have main wrappers for their respective test code like this:

```
#ifdef TEST_USB
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // the  main() routine for testing the usb code.
}
```

config.h
Which is included by all the c files has an entry like this:

```
// Uncomment below to test the serial
//#define TEST_SERIAL


// Uncomment below to test the spi code
//#define TEST_SPI

// Uncomment below to test the usb code
#define TEST_USB
```