# Compare two undefinded symbols in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I did not define both symboles SYMBOL1 and SYMBOL2, and I'm supprised when I see that the printf is called in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
#if (SYMBOL1==SYMBOL2)
    printf("Hello World");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Could you please explain why? any reference to the standard?

Comment: "the owls are not what they seem"

Comment: It's essentially equivalent to `#if (0 == 0)` which is true.

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate. Do we have any canonical "how does `#if` work?" post?

Comment: @Lundin maybe you could dupe with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085392/what-is-the-value-of-an-undefined-constant-used-in-if), but it's technically tagged [c++] (though the accepted answer cites both C and C++ standards).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the ISO C standard (`C11 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion`):

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary
> operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are ***replaced with the pp-number 0,*** and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated ...

In other words, your expression becomes `0 == 0`, which is obviously true. Hence the `printf` is included in the source stream.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will not catch that your MACRO is undefined and it will consider it a 0.
Since 0 == 0 `printf` will be executed.

The C standard says that all undefined identifiers there are replaced with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if both are defined, I think that if both (any) are undefined, you don't need to compile.

```
#if defined(SYMBOL1) && defined(SYMBOL1) && (SYMBOL1==SYMBOL2)
printf("Hello World");
#endif
```

(completely untested, but a rough idea).

edit: see also [Preprocessor check if multiple defines are not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237545/preprocessor-check-if-multiple-defines-are-not-defined)